# Периодический Будильник

Tags: android, android-alarm-manager

Всем привет! Делаю будильник на андроид, пересмотрев разные планировщики задач пришел к выводу что идеальным решением всё также остаётся AlarmManager. Реализовать одиночный будильник оказалось вовсе не проблема. Хотя и имеет свои сложности которые нужно не только понять, но и принять, уж слишком оно специфически. Для реализации периодического будильника тоже нет особых проблем, задаёшь точку во векторе времени, а именно к 1 января 1970г. добавляешь момент времени в котором должен сработать будильник в миллисекундах (благо есть Calendar и JodaTime) и добавляем периодичность, например сутки: 1000*60*60*24 (количество миллисекунд в сутках). Такая реализация хороша для ежедневного будильника, но кому нужен будильник который вас будет поднимать в ненавистный для вас час даже столь долгожданный выходной?

И так, есть две основных реализации установки срабатываний:

1. По дням - мы на каждый нужный день устанавливаем будильник, по его срабатыванию устанавливаем новый такой же со смещением в одну неделю.

   2. Ставим ежедневный будильник и проверяем, если сегодня должен сработать будильник то включаем будильник иначе просто его сбрасываем.

Оба этих варианта имеют огромную проблему:

1. Реализация сложная для понимания, в ней легко запутаться.

   2. Реализация больше похожа на набор свеженьких костылей чем на адекватное решение.
   3. У второго варианта, скорее всего будут ещё проблемы с энерго-эффективностью.

Если мы устанавливаем будильник на время которое прошло то будильник сработает скажем так мгновенно и вот делема, как предугадать адекватное поведение при варианте включения мобильного который был отключен в течение недели?

Есть ли у кого какие мысли какой из вариантов правильнее для обычного будильника и возможно кто знает где можно подсмотреть более менее адекватную реализацию? Так как большинство тех что я нашел это тестовые варианты "как пользоваться AlarmManager" остальные же слишком путанные, мне кажется что даже сам создатель не в состоянии объяснить как эта ересь работает...